Add user or process information in nftables logs
Hy,
Is it possible to customize nftables log's to add more informations ?
For example, it could be interesting to get users ( id, gid, ... )  or processes informations that try to out.
Example of classic log :
IN= OUT=ens18 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=8.8.8.8 LEN=60 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=64026 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51096 DPT=8888 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 

Regards

Good question! I would like to see a technical answer to explain why this is not possible with nftables and what it would take for such feature to be implemented, and what drawbacks would that bring.
